# Iterating over the number of axes of a 4D numpy array

Tags: python, loops, numpy-ndarray, nifti, nipype

this is probably very simple and I'm just overlooking something but here you go:

I have a 4D array in shape: (x,y,z,t)

How do i iterate over the number of axis of that array wit a for-loop? Not along a single axis but once for every axis?

Something like this:

```
for a in range(data.shape):
            data_20 = np.percentile(data_20, 80, axis=a, keepdims=True)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over range of dimensions of a `numpy.array` use `.ndim`

**Code:**

```
# convert data to numpy.array if data is a list

for i in range(np.array(data).ndim):
    print(i)
```

**Output**:

```
0
1
2
3
```